# Enabling desktop platform on existing flutter project with different flavors

Tags: macos, flutter, desktop

I am having issues with adding desktop platforms to existing projects.

I have followed their official [docs](https://flutter.dev/desktop#:%7E:text=After%20enabling%20desktop%20support%2C%20restart,no%2Dargument%20flutter%20config%20command.) on how to add macOS to the existing project. So basically you should:

1. master or dev channel of flutter.
2. should run `flutter create .` command

On this command, I get stuck, because we are using different flavors, and as a result, after step 2 I am getting:

> [   +2 ms] The Xcode project defines schemes: APN, AppStore, Debug,
> Staging [  +12 ms] "flutter create" took 2,539ms. [   +6 ms] You must
> specify a --flavor option to select one of the available schemes.

But the thing is that command `flutter create` does not have at all this option.
So ofc, running `flutter create --flavor=debug .` will not work

So the question is, does anyone know how to resolve this, and what's correct way of doing it?

Comment: I think you haven't maybe enabled it or something or while running you didn't select the device correctly. Watch this [video](https://youtu.be/70dqIVvoEyw), He shows how to work with cross platform applications. It works for me.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but he did everything from official documentation the same as I did :) It's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with web support and flavors. To resolve this, I've used a way around with:

`flutter create --org <identifier-for-one-of-the-flavors> .`

e.g.
`flutter create --org <com.example.flutter.staging> .`

This created and made a setup for specific flavor only, with a new `main` file, assets, scheme (flavor) etc. But, I've deleted all generated files except `web` folder and everything works fine as before, but now with web support.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately, workaround  but it's working. I would add something like  

`flutter create --org <com.example.flutter.staging> --platforms=macos .` 
so you don't need to remove unwanted files. Thanks